# Can I still use wxIndustrialControls for wxWidgets? LNK2019 Error

Tags: c++, user-interface, wxwidgets, lnk2019

For wxIndustrialControls, it's old but I wanted to know if it still works. "Why don't you try it yourself?". Well I did. This is what happens

First here is the source link if anyone wants to see it 
https://sourceforge.net/projects/wxsmithaddons/files/KWIC/
The file name is "kwxIndControlSource-0.3.0"

I made a folder in the include directory for wxWidgets called "kwic".

In my project, for example I am trying to create an LCDDisplay. So I do

`#include "kwic/LCDWindow.h"`

Then I declare my object in my header variables as follows

`kwxLCDDisplay* test;`

Then in my cpp

`test = new kwxLCDDisplay(this, wxPoint(0, 0), wxSize(100, 100));`

(There is a documentation file in the download that shows how you make each widget)

No errors with anything. I go to compile and run and I get

```
"Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall kwxLCDDisplay::kwxLCDDisplay(class wxWindow *,class wxPoint const &,class wxSize const &)" (??0kwxLCDDisplay@@QAE@PAVwxWindow@@ABVwxPoint@@ABVwxSize@@@Z) referenced in function "public: __thiscall MyFrame::MyFrame(void)" (??0MyFrame@@QAE@XZ)    eBikeSimulator  "Directory of my computer to MyFrame.obj    1"
```

I read "LNK2019 can occur when a declaration exists in a header file, but no matching definition is implemented." I checked the LCDWindow.h and cpp files and they all seem to be there. Any ideas of what am I missing? I feel like I maybe just don't know how to set up the files?

Edit: Updated, I fixed this issue, and then I got a deprecated message about the methods, so I updated the library on my own and the file then worked. But now I am getting the following

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   LNK2005 "class wxBrush * test" (?test@@3PAVwxBrush@@A) already defined in MyFrame.obj       MyDirectory\MyApp.obj   1   
Error   LNK2005 "private: static struct wxEventTableEntry const * const kwxLCDDisplay::sm_eventTableEntries" (?sm_eventTableEntries@kwxLCDDisplay@@0QBUwxEventTableEntry@@B) already defined in MyFrame.obj     MyDirectory\MyApp.obj   1   
Error   LNK2005 "protected: int __thiscall kwxLCDDisplay::DigitX(int)" (?DigitX@kwxLCDDisplay@@IAEHH@Z) already defined in MyFrame.obj      MyDirectory\MyApp.obj   1   
Error   LNK2005 "protected: int __thiscall kwxLCDDisplay::DigitY(void)" (?DigitY@kwxLCDDisplay@@IAEHXZ) already defined in MyFrame.obj      MyDirectory\MyApp.obj   1   
Error   LNK2005 "protected: int __thiscall kwxLCDDisplay::GetBitmapHeight(void)" (?GetBitmapHeight@kwxLCDDisplay@@IAEHXZ) already defined in MyFrame.obj        MyDirectory\MyApp.obj   1   
Error   LNK2005 "protected: int __thiscall kwxLCDDisplay::GetBitmapWidth(void)" (?GetBitmapWidth@kwxLCDDisplay@@IAEHXZ) already defined in MyFrame.obj      MyDirectory\MyApp.obj   1   
Error   LNK2005 "protected: int __thiscall kwxLCDDisplay::GetDigitHeight(void)" (?GetDigitHeight@kwxLCDDisplay@@IAEHXZ) already defined in MyFrame.obj      MyDirectory\MyApp.obj   1   
Error   LNK2005 "protected: int __thiscall kwxLCDDisplay::GetDigitWidth(void)" (?GetDigitWidth@kwxLCDDisplay@@IAEHXZ) already defined in MyFrame.obj        MyDirectory\MyApp.obj   1   
Error   LNK2005 "protected: static class wxEventHashTable kwxLCDDisplay::sm_eventHashTable" (?sm_eventHashTable@kwxLCDDisplay@@1VwxEventHashTable@@A) already defined in MyFrame.obj        MyDirectory\MyApp.obj   1   
Error   LNK2005 "protected: static struct wxEventTable const kwxLCDDisplay::sm_eventTable" (?sm_eventTable@kwxLCDDisplay@@1UwxEventTable@@B) already defined in MyFrame.obj     MyDirectory\MyApp.obj   1   
Error   LNK2005 "protected: unsigned char __thiscall kwxLCDDisplay::Decode(char)" (?Decode@kwxLCDDisplay@@IAEED@Z) already defined in MyFrame.obj       MyDirectory\MyApp.obj   1   
Error   LNK2005 "protected: virtual class wxEventHashTable & __thiscall kwxLCDDisplay::GetEventHashTable(void)const " (?GetEventHashTable@kwxLCDDisplay@@MBEAAVwxEventHashTable@@XZ) already defined in MyFrame.obj     MyDirectory\MyApp.obj   1   
Error   LNK2005 "protected: virtual struct wxEventTable const * __thiscall kwxLCDDisplay::GetEventTable(void)const " (?GetEventTable@kwxLCDDisplay@@MBEPBUwxEventTable@@XZ) already defined in MyFrame.obj      MyDirectory\MyApp.obj   1   
Error   LNK2005 "protected: void __thiscall kwxLCDDisplay::DoDrawing(class wxDC *)" (?DoDrawing@kwxLCDDisplay@@IAEXPAVwxDC@@@Z) already defined in MyFrame.obj      MyDirectory\MyApp.obj   1   
Error   LNK2005 "protected: void __thiscall kwxLCDDisplay::DrawDigit(class wxDC *,int,struct wxDigitData *)" (?DrawDigit@kwxLCDDisplay@@IAEXPAVwxDC@@HPAUwxDigitData@@@Z) already defined in MyFrame.obj        MyDirectory\MyApp.obj   1   
Error   LNK2005 "protected: void __thiscall kwxLCDDisplay::DrawSegment(class wxDC *,int,int,bool)" (?DrawSegment@kwxLCDDisplay@@IAEXPAVwxDC@@HH_N@Z) already defined in MyFrame.obj     MyDirectory\MyApp.obj   1   
Error   LNK2005 "protected: void __thiscall kwxLCDDisplay::DrawTwoDots(class wxDC *,int)" (?DrawTwoDots@kwxLCDDisplay@@IAEXPAVwxDC@@H@Z) already defined in MyFrame.obj     MyDirectory\MyApp.obj   1   
Error   LNK2005 "protected: void __thiscall kwxLCDDisplay::OnPaint(class wxPaintEvent &)" (?OnPaint@kwxLCDDisplay@@IAEXAAVwxPaintEvent@@@Z) already defined in MyFrame.obj      MyDirectory\MyApp.obj   1   
Error   LNK2005 "protected: void __thiscall kwxLCDDisplay::OnSize(class wxSizeEvent &)" (?OnSize@kwxLCDDisplay@@IAEXAAVwxSizeEvent@@@Z) already defined in MyFrame.obj      MyDirectory\MyApp.obj   1   
Error   LNK2005 "public: class wxColour __thiscall kwxLCDDisplay::GetGrayColour(void)" (?GetGrayColour@kwxLCDDisplay@@QAE?AVwxColour@@XZ) already defined in MyFrame.obj        MyDirectory\MyApp.obj   1   
Error   LNK2005 "public: class wxColour __thiscall kwxLCDDisplay::GetLightColour(void)" (?GetLightColour@kwxLCDDisplay@@QAE?AVwxColour@@XZ) already defined in MyFrame.obj      MyDirectory\MyApp.obj   1   
Error   LNK2005 "public: class wxString __thiscall kwxLCDDisplay::GetValue(void)" (?GetValue@kwxLCDDisplay@@QAE?AVwxString@@XZ) already defined in MyFrame.obj      MyDirectory\MyApp.obj   1   
Error   LNK2005 "public: int __thiscall kwxLCDDisplay::GetDigitsNeeded(class wxString)" (?GetDigitsNeeded@kwxLCDDisplay@@QAEHVwxString@@@Z) already defined in MyFrame.obj      MyDirectory\MyApp.obj   1   
Error   LNK2005 "public: int __thiscall kwxLCDDisplay::GetNumberDigits(void)" (?GetNumberDigits@kwxLCDDisplay@@QAEHXZ) already defined in MyFrame.obj       MyDirectory\MyApp.obj   1   
Error   LNK2005 "public: virtual __thiscall kwxLCDDisplay::~kwxLCDDisplay(void)" (??1kwxLCDDisplay@@UAE@XZ) already defined in MyFrame.obj      MyDirectory\MyApp.obj   1   
Error   LNK2005 "public: void __thiscall kwxLCDDisplay::SetGrayColour(class wxColour)" (?SetGrayColour@kwxLCDDisplay@@QAEXVwxColour@@@Z) already defined in MyFrame.obj     MyDirectory\MyApp.obj   1   
Error   LNK2005 "public: void __thiscall kwxLCDDisplay::SetLightColour(class wxColour)" (?SetLightColour@kwxLCDDisplay@@QAEXVwxColour@@@Z) already defined in MyFrame.obj       MyDirectory\MyApp.obj   1   
Error   LNK2005 "public: void __thiscall kwxLCDDisplay::SetNumberDigits(int)" (?SetNumberDigits@kwxLCDDisplay@@QAEXH@Z) already defined in MyFrame.obj      MyDirectory\MyApp.obj   1   
Error   LNK2005 "public: void __thiscall kwxLCDDisplay::SetValue(class wxString)" (?SetValue@kwxLCDDisplay@@QAEXVwxString@@@Z) already defined in MyFrame.obj       MyDirectory\MyApp.obj   1   
Error   LNK2005 "public: __thiscall kwxLCDDisplay::kwxLCDDisplay(class wxWindow *,class wxPoint const &,class wxSize const &)" (??0kwxLCDDisplay@@QAE@PAVwxWindow@@ABVwxPoint@@ABVwxSize@@@Z) already defined in MyFrame.obj        MyDirectory\MyApp.obj   1   
Error   LNK1169 one or more multiply defined symbols found      application.exe 1
```

Comment: Did you include `LCDWindow.cpp` in your project or link with a library including it?

Comment: @VZ. Thanks for the response. That seemed to solve the issue by including the cpp file (I swear I thought I saw it included already), but after I was getting deprecated issues. I updated the library myself to compile, but I'm now getting this error list, I'll update the original post in a moment with it.

Comment: It looks like you included the `.cpp` file in a header or something like that?

Comment: Hi. Yes, I did. I removed it and included it in the source file instead. I got it to display! 
The weird thing is someone else working on this with me told Visual Studio to ignore the error, and they got it working, even though they didn't update the libraries like I did? O.o

Comment: Ignoring linker errors is absolutely never the right thing to do. Don't trust everything you read on the internet.

Comment: Yes, I figured. Why is that so, what are some repercussions, just compiling issues?

Comment: No, your program can mysteriously behave incorrectly. Don't ignore linker errors, make sure you understand and fix them.

Comment: @TheCoolest2, just understand that the error is an error and you still suppose to fix all of them pior to executing the code.

Comment: Thank you guys very much. Have a good day.